# Der Lehrer erklärt den Studenten die Grammatik

Tags: pronoun

*Der Lehrer erklärt ihnen die Brief.* 
*Der Lehrer erklärt sie den Studenten.*
*Der Lehrer erklärt sie ihnen.* 
Why do Germans use *sie* to indicate *die Grammatik*? I would definitely use *it* to indicate grammar

Comment: den Brief? (der Brief -> den Brief). Die Grammatik -> sie. Was sollten wir sonst benutzen? Es?

Comment: Your question pinpoints again the fundamental difference between (biological) sex and (grammatical) gender. In a nutshell: they are two unrelated concepts. We have more questions based on that difference, so this will likely be a duplicate and subsequently closed.

Comment: This is very basic knowledge of German, that you will learn within the very first lessons. Every book on German grammar contains a chapter on grammatical genders of nouns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

German, English and Spanish belong to the same family of languages.

Although German is very close to English in many ways, the concept of the gender of words is more like in romance languages (Spanish, French, Italian, ...):

In those languages all nouns are either male or female. The word "*it*" does not exist, but the word "*he*" or "*she*" is used depending on the gender of the substantive.

Example (translated from Spanish to English):

> This is my house.
>
> I like **her** very much.
>
> And this is my knife.
>
> I also like **him**.

... because the word "*it*" does not exist in Spanish and the word "*house*" (*la casa*) is **female** in Spanish and the word "*knife*" (*el cuchillo*) is **male**.

**In German** it is more complex. There are three "genders": Male, female and neutral.

However, although there are three genders, the concept is similar to Spanish: Each word has a gender and the only way to find out the gender of the word is to look up the word in the dictionary.

As Stephie already wrote these genders have nothing to do with biological genders as you can see in the following counterexamples:

- "*Die Karre*" is female, "*der Kraftwagen*" is male and "*das Auto*" is neutral although all three words more or less have the same meaning.
- "*Das Mädchen*" is neutral although a girl is female.
- Some words (example: "*Butter*") are even male in some German dialects and female in other German dialects (so it depends on the dialect you speak if something is male or female)!

So please **DON'T** assume a relation as described below - because it is simply wrong:

> er = he
>
> sie = she
>
> es = it

The word "*die*" indicates that "***die** Grammatik*" is female.

Comment: English had three genders for nouns too, many centuries ago. But it lost those genders. The english gender system only survived in pronouns, and - in contrast to German - those English pronouns no longer refer to grammatical  genders. They refer to biological genders with the default value *"it"* for non living things.